# Changing plot with Python and Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have file which contains a list of coordinates. I would like to take each point and plot it one after another, creating some sort of animation.

Assuming I am getting the data like this, what should I do in order to have each point plotted for a split second and then replaced with the next one?

```
...
for line in f:
    data = line.split(',')
    x_coord = data[0]
    y_coord = data[1]
    ...
```

Comment: Maybe you can use [matplotlib.animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132798/python-animation-graph)?

Comment: See questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470324/first-set-of-scatter-plot-data-remains-on-the-graph-during-animation-with-pyth/19471017#19471017

Answer (score 1):

Plotting one by one isn't the answer - you're unlikely to be able to control the speed at which each `plot` call pops up on the screen, as that may be window-manager dependent and won't create a good user experience.

If you don't need a *live* animation, you could render each plot as a PNG, then use mencoder to generate the animation, as described in the [Matplotlib FAQ](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#make-a-movie).

If you do want a live animation, that's what [matplotlib's animation](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) is for. Steinar Lima links to a good [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132798/python-animation-graph) above.